# How to create a setState wrapper that accepts arbitrary objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, arguments

I'm working with the setState method from REACT, and almost every setState call in my code looks something like the following:

```
this.setState({..some_stuff...}, ()=> some_standard_method(this.state));
```

And so that naturally suggests that if i had a method of the form

```
customSetState(args) {
    this.setState(args, () => some_standard_method(this.state));

}
```

Then I can make my code a lot less verbose by replacing each of my setState calls above with the following below

```
customSetState(...some_stuff...).bind(this)
```

But I'm not sure how to write this method. What I mean by that, is that the setState method doesn't take a single variable exactly, but an arbitrary object with arbitrary parameters specified. So in the line:

```
customSetState(args) { ...
```

Do i need to make any changes to the input variable "args" to indicate that i'm accepting arbitary defined objects?

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works? `setState` takes a single object. You pass the single object to your function in a single variable. Nothing special needs to be done.

Comment: logically speaking i saw no reason to assume it would work, but i can try! will get back to you with what the outcome is

Comment: What you pass in to `setState` is just an object literal (eg, `{ color: 'red', number: 5 }`). It doesn't matter if it is passed directly or stored in a variable first or passed through a function parameter. Logically that part should work, as long as you are using the correct `this`, which it looks like you take care of with `bind`. As an aside, why are you passing `this.state` to `some_standard_method` in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to achieve that using the spread operator and a rest parameter:

```js
function setStateSimulation(...args) {
    console.log(`My three parameters are ${args[0]}, ${args[1]} and ${args[2]}`);
    const callback = args[args.length - 1];
    callback();
}

function myCustomSetStateSimulation(...args) {
    setStateSimulation(...args, () => {
        console.log('My custom callback');
    });

}

myCustomSetStateSimulation("a", "B", "c");
```